# Adding data to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

My code is working but data is not getting updated it is overwriting the previous data.
Here is my code-

```
const Push = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    database.ref("address").set({
        state: user.state,
        district:user.district,
        street:user.street,
        building:user.building,
    }).catch(alert);
  }
```

Comment: @AlexMamo That's a Firestore API, while OP here is using Realtime Database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, yes. Missed that `.ref(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge the properties you specify with any existing data, you can use `update` instead of `set`:

```
database.ref("address").update({
    state: user.state,
    district:user.district,
    street:user.street,
    building:user.building,
})
```

If you instead want to keep a list of addresses, you can use `push` instead of `set`:

```
database.ref("address").push({
    state: user.state,
    district:user.district,
    street:user.street,
    building:user.building,
})
```